# Mysql failed to start

Tags: daemon, mysql

I have installed mysql-5.6.14 from source pack

trying to start:

> vaio1@vaio1-VPCEA3S1E:mysqld

```
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root  
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.mysqld: Unknown error 1146
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 2013-11-17 13:22:19 1777 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
 2013-11-17 13:22:19 1777 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
 2013-11-17 13:22:19 1777 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.14 started; log sequence number 1600677
 2013-11-17 13:22:19 1777 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you got the MySQL 5.6 binary but my.cnf and data file is older version.

have you read [*MySQL upgrade Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html)?

main reason MySQL has dead is :

```
Unknown error 1146 2013-11-17 13:22:18 1777 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table.
Please run mysql_upgrade to create it
```

see [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html) how to use mysql_upgrade. most of error message is related to *deprecated options*.

Comment: I found this http://serverfault.com/questions/527422/mysql-upgrade-is-failing-with-no-real-reason-given.  Probably you did not give login argument.

Answer (score 10):

Open the terminal and run this command for starting mysql service:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

while mysql service is running, then open other terminal and run:

```
$ sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Comment: Very easy and clearly, works fine, upgrade successfully thank you very much @Silva, this is best answer!

Comment: I tried this solution on CentOs 6, I recommend using this solution to All

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqld reads this standard configuration file and can not read the 5.5 message file in
5.6, leading to this error.

Solutions :

1. pass your configuration file to mysql_install_db

./scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=my.cnf

2. use --no-defaults, not to read other configuration files

./scripts/mysql_install_db --no-defaults --basedir=/home/praveen/mysql-5.6.10-linux-x86_65 
--datadir=/home/praveen/data
```

Comment: The scripts folder seemed to have disappeared from the tar files

Answer (score 0):

> I have compiled from the sourceforge zip :[mysql-5.6.14](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql.mirror/files/MySQL%205.6.14/)
>
> Trying to mysql_upgrade:
>
> vaio1@vaio1-VPCEA3S1E:~/Téléchargements/mysql-5.6.14$ mysql_upgrade

```
  Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
  Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
  FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

> vaio1@vaio1-VPCEA3S1E:~/Téléchargements/mysql-5.6.14$ mysqlcheck

```
  Variables (--variable-name=value)
  and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
  --------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
  all-databases                     FALSE
  all-in-1                          FALSE
  auto-repair                       FALSE
  bind-address                      (No default value)
  character-sets-dir                (No default value)
  compress                          FALSE
  databases                         FALSE
  debug-check                       FALSE
  debug-info                        FALSE
  default-character-set             (No default value)
  default-auth                      (No default value)
  fast                              FALSE
  fix-db-names                      FALSE
  fix-table-names                   FALSE
  force                             FALSE
  extended                          FALSE
  host                              (No default value)
  write-binlog                      TRUE
  plugin-dir                        (No default value)
  port                              0
  quick                             FALSE
  silent                            FALSE
  skip-database                     (No default value)
  socket                            (No default value)
  ssl                               FALSE
  ssl-ca                            (No default value)
  ssl-capath                        (No default value)
  ssl-cert                          (No default value)
  ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
  ssl-key                           (No default value)
  ssl-crl                           (No default value)
  ssl-crlpath                       (No default value)
  ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
  use-frm                           FALSE
  user                              (No default value)
```

> I don't understand why

```
 user                              (No default value)
```

> In my file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
 user = mysql
```

> vaio1@vaio1-VPCEA3S1E:~/Téléchargements/mysql-5.6.14$ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

```
 131118 10:10:04 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
 touch: impossible de faire un touch «/var/log/mysql/error.log»: Permission non accordée
 chmod: impossible d'accéder à «/var/log/mysql/error.log»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type ## No files or directory
 131118 10:10:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: 129: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: 1: eval: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
 touch: impossible de faire un touch «/var/log/mysql/error.log»: Permission non accordée
 chown: impossible d'accéder à «/var/log/mysql/error.log»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type ## No files or directory
 chmod: impossible d'accéder à «/var/log/mysql/error.log»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type 
 131118 10:10:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: 129: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
```

> ...$ mysqlcheck --all-databases --check-upgrade --auto-repair

```
 mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

> Trying this: sudo chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
>   also .. chown..var/log/mysql/

```
 .. change nothing
```

> YES! maybe problem from default user;

```
 sudo cmod 777 var/log/mysql/  ## just test lol
```

> Trying     mysqld

```
 vaio1@vaio1-VPCEA3S1E:~/Téléchargements/mysql-5.6.14$ mysqld
 2013-11-18 11:36:36 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
 2013-11-18 11:36:36 24679 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
 2013-11-18 11:36:36 24679 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root
```

> 2013-11-18 11:36:36 24679 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
>
> Coping errmsg.sys

```
 sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/share/english/errmsg.sys /usr/share/errmsg.sys
 sudo chown mysql /usr/share/errmsg.sys
```

[Resolve /usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102875/ysql-5-5-starts-and-then-instantly-stops-on-ubuntu-10-10)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the list of MySQL "ini" files are present in : "MySQL\MySQL Server 5.2\" folder, replace them from your frined. 
I wasted so much time and still dont know the root cause of the problem. 
Do check ".err" file present in "data" folder for errors if any. 
Now start the service & Done. 
Its just makes entry somewhere & u try to debug for the problem soluton, instead this was faster approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue as mentioned in this question and tried lot of solutions, at last I figured out what was wrong. The issue came with the  server upgrading. Files from mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 replaced those in MySQL-server-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64, so after reinstalling, the server comes back. Here is what I did for a furture reference.

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys
MySQL-server-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64
$ rpm -e mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64
$ rpm -ivh --replacepkgs MySQL-*
```